# How to remove only the last forward slash in the field?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, json

I have a json file where I need to remove the last forward slashes only. See the example:

```
{"url":"http://example.com/vary/file/","originalUrl":"http://example.com/vary/file/","applications":[{.........}]}
```

I just want the data to look like:

```
{"url":"example.com/vary/file","originalUrl":"example.com/vary/file","applications":[{.........}]}
```

How can I do this with `sed`?

Comment: [Backslash or a (forward) slash?](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/topics/BackslashVsForwardSlash/)

Comment: @Melebius :P it should be forward I guess.

Comment: How big is the file, and can double slash blindly be replaced by a single one?

Comment: @JacobVlijm might happen... the file is large GBs

Comment: @JacobVlijm nothing as such. I was just trying to use `sed`nothing else.

Comment: Your output doesn't have the `http://` from the input.

Comment: @muru oops I forgot to add it. But is it possible to have it without http also?

Comment: Removing `http://` should be easy, just another `sed 's,http://,,g'`

Comment: @muru Yes I think that's easy. I think that's why I haven't added it to the question previously :P :)

Comment: If I may voice my opinion, @JafferWilson , consider starting to learn using Python or Perl and their respective `json` APIs (and maybe learn those in the process ).  I understand it's fun and simple sometimes to use `sed` or other tools, but `json` APIs were created specifically for that purpose. Of course, structuring `json` data properly.  Not trying to teach you what to do, but seriously - you can save yourself a lot of time if you start using proper tools for proper job.

Comment: Also , can you please edit your question to include that you want `http://`  part removed. Because without that, it makes Zanna's and my answer effectively only half-correct.  What about `https://` ? do you want those removed as well ?

Comment: I appreciate  @Serg suggestion. I really want to learn python at least. But the thin is currently workload is extreme high and I could not manage to have time to eat or sleep. But I can assure that I will learn.

Comment: @Serg I can do that with a simple `sed` command from command line.

Comment: @JafferWilson well, I've included removal of http:// into my answer. Do you want me to roll back to original one, with only slash removal or leave it as is ?

Comment: @Serg no leave it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took the liberty to modify OP's input slightly, because as it stands , it's not properly structured `json` data (due to the `{...}` part) and implemented a small python script that works with multiple dictionaries, assuming that we're dealing with a dictionary per line. Additionally, as has been discussed in the comments to the question, OP also wanted to remove `http://` part.

The script below implements everything discussed above.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json,sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f: 
    for line in f:
        data=json.loads(line)
        if data["url"][-1] == '/':
            data["url"]=data["url"][:-1].replace('http://','')
        if data["originalUrl"][-1] == '/':
            data["originalUrl"]=data["originalUrl"][:-1].replace('http://','')
        json.dump(data,sys.stdout)
        print("")
```

Test run:

```
$ cat input.txt                                                                                 
{"url":"http://example.com/vary/file/","originalUrl":"http://example.com/vary/file/","applications":[{"somedata": "blah"}]}
{"url":"http://another-example.com/vary/file/","originalUrl":"http://example.com/vary/file/","applications":[{"somedata": "blah"}]}
$ ./remove_slash.py input.txt                                                                   
{"url": "example.com/vary/file", "applications": [{"somedata": "blah"}], "originalUrl": "example.com/vary/file"}
{"url": "another-example.com/vary/file", "applications": [{"somedata": "blah"}], "originalUrl": "example.com/vary/file"}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you insist on using `sed`, you could just match the `/"` combination, to remove the last `/` in every field, assuming it will not occur somewhere you want to keep it (which should be fairly reliable in this case)

```
$ sed 's|/"|"|g' file
{"url":"http://example.com/vary/file","originalUrl":"http://example.com/vary/file","applications":[{.........}]}
```

I used `|` to delimit instead of `/` to save a backslash. You need `g` for multiple matches on the same line.

Here's a way to take out the `http://` as well in the same call:

```
$ sed -r 's|"http://([^"]+)/"|"\1"|g' url
{"url":"example.com/vary/file","originalUrl":"example.com/vary/file","applications":[{.........}]}
```

`([^"]+)` will match anything between `"http://` and `/"` that isn't a `"`. We save this part with `()` and reference with `\1`.

Answer (score 5):

A late one:

a simple, purely text based python option:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as data:
    for l in data:
        print(("").join(l.strip().replace("http://", "").rsplit("/", 1)))
```

Or, just for fun, another way of saying it:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

[print(("").join(l.strip().replace("http://", "").rsplit("/", 1))) for l in open(sys.argv[1])]
```

doing both the string replacement/removal (`http://`) and the slash removal in appr. 47 seconds on 14.000.000 million lines, on my ancient system.

To use:

```
python3 /path/to/script.py /path/to/inputfile > outputfile
```

#### Explanation

As usual, python is quite readable, but in detail:

- `rsplit("/", 1)` splits the line *from the right* (hence the `r`) by the delimiter `/` *only once* (hence the `1`)
- `l.replace("http://", "")` replaces `http://` by an empty string
- `("").join()` joins the list, that was created by `rsplit()` again into a line

Answer (score 0):

**Input JSON file (test.json):**

```
{"url":"http://example.com/vary/file/","originalUrl":"http://example.com/vary/file/"}
```

- Code to modify as per requirement and re-write to same file:

  ```
  import json
   with open("test.json") as fh:
      data = json.load(fh)

   for k,v in data.items():
      data[k] = v.replace("http://","").strip("/")

   with open("test.json","w") as fh:
      json.dump(data,fh)
  ```

**Output:**

```
{"url": "example.com/vary/file", "originalUrl": "example.com/vary/file"}
```

All operations at once, replaces `http://` with `""` and strips `/` at the end of the string.

```
replace("http://","").strip("/")
```